# How to change axis units in strip plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have a code like this:

```
var = 'Fuel_Type'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15.7, 6.27)
sns.stripplot(x = var, y ='Price', data = data1, jitter=0.2, palette="Set2", size=10, marker="o", edgecolor="gray", alpha=.5)
```

and this gives plot:

[image: Chart]

How to customize Y axis to have labels 10, 20... ?

Data looks like this:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBq0Y.png)

Comment: can you give small sample of the dataset?

Comment: Convert your strings to numbers.

Comment: looks like you're using strings, not floats for "Price"

Comment: Try `data1['Price`] = data1['Price`].astype(float)`.  If that shows an error, you might need to change the culpable values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# x-axis tick positions and labels - change it with your own value and labels
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'])

# y-axis positions and labels - change it with your own value and labels
plt.yticks([1, 3, 5], ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Or in 2 steps like below:

```
g = sns.stripplot(x = var, y ='Price', data = data1, jitter=0.2, palette="Set2", size=10, marker="o", edgecolor="gray", alpha=.5)
```

## change it with your own interval values:

```
g.set_yticks(range(len(s_x)+1))
g.set_yticklabels(['10','20','30','40','50'])
```